# Own programmed LINQ extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well, I have this extension method:

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{ 
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    return list[0];
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
doubles.First()
```

`doubles` is a list with double numbers

Now I want to use the same extension method for my `persons` list. This is how I want to call it:

```
persons.First(x => x.Age < 60)
```

I should return the first person where the Age is < 60. What do I have to change in my code of the extension method to make this work. At the moment I can't compile because of this error:

```
CS1501: No overload for method 'First' takes 1 arguments
```

Comment: Why. Why are you writing an extension method that is worse than a built-one that already exists?

Comment: So you need an overload of the method taking a `Func<T, bool>` parameter. You might also have a look at the [LINQ source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a filter or predicate to accomplish what you want to do.

I created this example for you to take a look
https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnMktf

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    

public class Person
{
    public int Age {get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person() {Age = 60});
        persons.Add(new Person() {Age = 10});
        
        var result = persons.First(p => p.Age < 60);
        var resultWithoutParams = persons.First();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("This is the result {0}", result.Age));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("This is the result {0}", resultWithoutParams.Age));
    }
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> filter = null)
    { 
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if(filter == null)
            return list[0];
        
        foreach(var item in list) 
            if(filter(item)) return item;
        
        return default(TSource);
    }
}
```

this method is only extending the list but It is not accepting any arguments.

Comment: Yeah I dont't want to use LINQ and I also want the same method without parameters

Comment: In your call to `First`, you pass in a parameter, a `Func<T, bool>`. Therefore, you can't have an extension method taking no parameters that accepts a parameter.